# I want to stop a group of completed threads, wait for uncompleted threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

I need a group of threads to run at the same time, and then another group of threads after that. For example, `10` threads start working, and then `10` or `15` other threads.

Of course, the first approach I've tried was to create a loop.

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("hi");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

But the problem is when scenario like this happens: imagine if in first iteration, 8 threads finished their tasks, and `2` threads take longer time. The next `10` threads won't start until all `8` + `2` (completed and not completed) threads finish. while, I want an approach where `8` threads get replaced by `8` of waiting to start threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bare Threads

It can be done using bare `Thread` and `Runnable` without diving into more advance technologies.

For that, you need to perform the following steps:

- define your task (provide an implementation of the `Runnable` interface);
- generate a collection of Threads creating based on this task);
- start every thread;
- invoke `join()` on every of these thread (**note** that firstly we need to start all threads).

That's how it might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("hi");
    
    int counter = 0;
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("iteration: " + counter++);

        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(task));
        }

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }

        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Instead of managing your Threads manually, it definitely would be wise to look at the facilities provided by the implementations of the `ExecutorService` interfaces.

Things would be a bit earthier if you use `Callable` interface for your task instead of `Runnable`. `Callable` is more handy in many cases because it allows obtaining the result from the worker-thread and also propagating an exception if thing went wrong (as opposed `run()` would force you to catch every checked exception). If you have in mind something more interesting than printing a dummy message, you might find `Callable` to be useful for your purpose.

## ExecutorService.invokeAll() + Callable

`ExecutorService` has a blocking method [`invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) which expects a collection of the callable-tasks and return a list of completed `Future` objects when all the tasks are done.

To generate a light-weight collection of repeated elements (since we need to fire a bunch of identical tasks) we can use utility method [`Collections.nCopies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)).

Here's a sample code which repeatedly runs a dummy task:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

while (true) {
    executor.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(10, () -> {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return true;
    }));
}
```

To make sure that it does what expected, we can add a counter of iterations and display it on the console and `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` to avoid cluttering the output very fast (for the same reason, the number of tasks reduced to `3`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    int counter = 0;
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("iteration: " + counter++);
        
        executor.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(3, () -> {
            System.out.println("hi");
            return true;
        }));
        
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
iteration: 0
hi
hi
hi
iteration: 1
hi
hi
hi
... etc.
```

## CompletableFuture.allOf().join() + Runnable

Another possibility is to use `CompletableFuture` API, and it's method [`allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)) which expects a *varargs* of submitted tasks in the form `CompletableFuture` and return a single `CompletableFuture` which would be completed when all provided arguments are done.

In order to synchronize the execution of the tasks with the main thread, we need to invoke [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()) on the resulting `CompletableFuture` instance.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("hi");

    int counter = 0;
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("iteration: " + counter++);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(
            Stream.generate(() -> task)
                .limit(3)
                .map(t -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(t, executor))
                .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new)
        ).join();
        
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
iteration: 0
hi
hi
hi
iteration: 1
hi
hi
hi
... etc.
```

## ScheduledExecutorService

I suspect you might interested in scheduling these tasks instead of running them reputedly. If that's the case, have a look at `ScheduledExecutorService` and it's methods [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`scheduleWithFixedDelay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Answer (score 0):

For adding tasks to threads and replacing them you can use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You can create it by using:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```